# Asymptotics of cumulative Liouville function under RH versus simple random walk

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, random-walks, riemann-hypothesis

The expectation values of the [1D simple random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk) $S_n$ can be [shown](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html) to have the asymptotic behavior of
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{1/2}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}, \tag{1}\label{1}$$

with $a_n = S_n$.

On the other hand, the Riemann Hypothesis is famously equivalent to the statement that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{1/2 +\varepsilon}} = 0, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$ and setting $a_n=L(n)$, the [cumulative (or summatory) Liouville function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvilleFunction.html) $L(n)=\sum_n \lambda(n)$.

I am interested in about what we know on the difference between the two asymptotic behaviours \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}. Clearly the random walk asymptotics \eqref{1} implies \eqref{2} but not vice versa.

How can it be shown that $a_n=L(n)$ violates \eqref{1}, would its fulfillment have interesting implications? Are there other/simple examples of $a_n$ that fulfill \eqref{2}?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, considering for $n$ a primorial, you get exactly half its divisors having an odd number of prime factors and thus one half having an even number of prime factors. So the difference wrt the simple random walk you mention as far as the asymptotic is concerned might come from the numbers less than $n$ and not dividing it.

Comment: Note that this also works for any $n$ whose at least one $p$-adic valuation is odd.

Comment: In the first equation, is $a_n$ supposed to be the *expected value* of $S_n$? Any individual random walk will almost surely satisfy different extremal asymptotics, see [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm). I don't know about $L(n)$, but the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) is expected to have different extremal asymptotics, and I suspect same should go for $L(n)$.

Comment: One thing for certain is that the sequence $L(n)/n^{1/2}$ doesn't have a limit - it has positive limsup and negative liminf, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function#Conjectures_on_weighted_summatory_functions)

Comment: So you say considering only square free numbers we would have (1), right?

Comment: The sequence $M(n)/n^{1/2}$ does not have a limit either.

Comment: @wojowu not sure if I understand your statement correctly: Asuming RH one can show that limsup and liminf are bounded, sure. But that does not tell us that this is in deed the case, nor does it show that the limit doesn't exist, right?

Comment: RH does not imply that limsup and liminf are bounded, they are expected to be infinite. The fact the liminf and limsup are negative and positive respectively is a nontrivial (and unconditional) result, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture#Disproof_of_the_conjecture) for references and explicit bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured the remarks I gave in the comments deserve to be gathered up into a more coherent form as an answer.

One thing I will start with is that comparing $L(n)$ (or $M(n)$, the Mertens function) to the values $S_n$ is arguably not the right heuristic. Indeed, $S_n$ averages over all random walks, which can have their peaks and troughs at different places, and so they cancel out. Analysing a single random walk gives a different asymptotic: this is governed by [the law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm), which asserts that the random walk will oscillate with extremal values on the order of $\pm\sqrt{2n\log\log n}$.

However it turns out that for subtle arithmetic reasons we do not expect the arithmetic functions of interest to reach the same bounds. Most literature (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310381v1)) concerns the Mertens function $M(n)$ so I will discuss this one, but all the relevant heuristics should also hold for $L(n)$. An unpublished conjecture of Gonek is that the maximal order of $|M(n)|$ is not $\sqrt{n\log\log n}$, but rather $\sqrt{n}(\log\log\log n)^{5/4}$, which in particular implies that the ratio $|M(n)|/\sqrt{n}$ is unbounded.

While Gonek's conjecture is still open, as is unboundedness of $|M(n)|/\sqrt{n}$, we do have unconditional results which imply that this sequence does not have a limit. Specifically, we know that $M(n)/\sqrt{n}$ has strictly negative liminf and strictly positive limsup (indeed, they are at least $\pm1.8$ respectively, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture#Disproof_of_the_conjecture) for more details and references.) This shows that $|M(n)|/\sqrt{n}$ crosses zero infintiely often, and infinitely often it takes values greater than $1$, so it cannot have a limit. (Same is known for Liouville though with different bounds on liminf and limsup, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function#Conjectures_on_weighted_summatory_functions).)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "[...]  is arguably not the right heuristic."?

Comment: The rest of that paragraph is an elaboration. You should treat analysis of $M(n)$ as analysis of a single random walk, not an average over all of them.